# c# register internet explorer toolbar by user

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, registry, toolbar

I want to add a button icon on the internet explorer toolbar using the c#. The code is:`Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar").SetValue(guid,name)`. But it will create for all users. Now i want to register the button for current user.
    I had tried the 'CurrentUser', but it not work. What's the registry key for the current user?

Answer (score 0):

CurrentUser should work but you need to execute your app with elevated privileges.

Go to your VS project properties and set your linker -> manifest file and check UAC Execution Level. Select the requireAdministrator option.